# jQuery mobile tap/hold

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery, how would you find if a mobile device user is holding down on a div?  During this time, a variable will be set to value X--if the div is not being touched, the variable will be set to value Y.

I've thought of two ways to do this, but neither of which I know the code for:

1. While the div is being touched, if the variable isn't already X, set the variable to X.  This method is rather inefficient
2. When the div is tapped, set the variable to X.  When it's released (like .mouseup), set the variable to Y.

I'd rather use the second option if possible.  I'm not sure if .mouseup/.mousedown work in mobile browsers.

Comment: Did you try mouse events in a mobile browser before you asked? They work the same in a mobile browser as mouse events in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to use jQuery touchstart event:

```
$(".selector").bind("touchstart", function(e) {

 //Do your things

});
```

Comment: However, that only triggers after the selector has been held for long enough.  I want my event to trigger as soon as it's occurred, but have the opposite event (like the mousedown/mouseup events) trigger immediately after the selector is released.

Comment: Seems like I missunderstood the problem. See my updated answer :)

Comment: It works if I tap it, but if I hold onto the div, it highlights the div instead of running the code.

Comment: how about touchstart?